# It was compiled on Arduino IDE. Now, how to utilize existing libraries when using another compiler

Tags: ros2, cmake, build

I used it by adding a library to the Arduino IDE.
Due to circumstances, I have to use build-command, but I cannot proceed due to a basic library problem. (ex arduino.h)
So, I am currently curious about the package.xml command that adds Arduino's basic library and the command in CMakeLists.txt.
thank you
Have a nice week.